# Auto calculate amount of specific cell values filled in current year - every year

Tags: vba, excel, date, countif

I'm trying to get my excel sheet to pull a list of people who have visited for a certain visit each year - example - I want to see how often people attend for annual vaccine - this is inputted into row 27 of each worksheet ( except the results)and then I use lookup to fill the latest result into the top of the persons file in cell **E13** (also on each worksheet).

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(27:27<>""),27:27)
```

But then I want my **Results** sheet to count how many people got the annual vaccine this year in cell **B14** ( and automatically calculate for each year going forward - so that in 2017 I ' have to change the code.

I'm using a module to pull the results from across different worksheets (each person gets a worksheet): (using this for other results also but the current year is stumping me)

```
Function myCountIfs(Rng1 As Range, Criteria1, Rng2 As Range, Criteria2) As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Summary-Sheet" And ws.Name <> "Notes" And ws.Name <> "Results" Then
        myCountIfs = myCountIfs + WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range(Rng1.Address), Criteria1, ws.Range(Rng2.Address), Criteria2)
    End If
Next ws
End Function
```

I can'f figure out how to get it to pull the info from the current year while using this module. 
I tried using but I have to manually change it every year and I want it to autochange

```
=my3COUNTIFS(E13,"<="&YEAR(2016),E13,">="&YEAR(2015)-1, I7,"Yes")
```

with the following VBA: The I7 is another function that must be called in - if I7 is "Yes" AND E13 has a date this year then info to be counted

```
    Function my3CountIfs(Rng1 As Range, Criteria1 As String, Rng2 As Range, Criteria2 As String, Rng3 As Range, Criteria3 As String) As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

Select Case ws.Name
    Case "Summary-Sheet", "Notes", "Results"
        ' do nothing

    Case Else
         my3CountIfs = my3CountIfs + Application.CountIfs(ws.Range(Rng1.Address), Criteria1, ws.Range(Rng2.Address), Criteria2)

End Select
Next ws

End Function
```

Here is the person worksheet (they are all the same)
[Persons file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5trF.jpg)

and here is the results page where I want the year to go in cell B14
[Results page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBgz9.jpg)

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Your description is unclear. Please note that we can't see your workbooks, so some things that are obvious for you are unclear for us. For example: why do you have to change your code? To change range for particular year?

Comment: Could you show an example of how you call the `MyCountIfs` function?

Comment: Sorry @Limak  - I dont have to change the code - I just don't know what code to use to get the year - I'm using '=my3COUNTIFS(B50,"<="&YEAR(2016),B50,">="&YEAR(2015)-1, I7,"Yes")' but its not working

Comment: Get year from what? Date variable? Cell value? You say 'code', which I understand  as VB code, but maybe you are writing about some formula?

Comment: @Limak I want to get the year from the date in the Persons file cell E13 and yes its a variable date - each person will get the vaccine on a different date - and not necessariy the same year - so I want to see how many people got it this year. By code I mean formula - sorry

Comment: @Ciara Jacob see my answer and code below and let me know if that works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the modified UDF below:

```
Option Explicit

Function my3CountIfs(Rng1 As Range, EndYear As Variant, Rng2 As Range, StartYear As Variant, Rng3 As Range, Criteria3 As String) As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Summary-Sheet", "Notes", "Results"
            ' do nothing

        Case Else
            ' needed to use regular Ifs here
            If Year(CDate(ws.Range(Rng1.Address))) >= CInt(StartYear) And Year(CDate(ws.Range(Rng2.Address))) <= CInt(EndYear) Then
                If ws.Range(Rng3.Address) = Criteria3 Then  ' if 3rd range (I7) = "Yes"
                    my3CountIfs = my3CountIfs + 1
                End If
            End If

    End Select
Next ws

End Function
```

However, in order to call it from Excel sheet's (Cell B14 in your example) , use the line below :

```
=my3CountIfs(E13,2016,E13,2015,I7,"Yes")
```

See screen-shot below for example of using this UDF in Excel : 2 sheets have "YES" in cells I7, and date in Cell E13 is `15/12/2016`. Therefore the result is 2.

[image]

Comment: Note that if you really want it to update next year without you doing anything, then you can use `YEAR(NOW())` instead of `2016` and `YEAR(NOW())-1` instead of `2015` in the parameters.

Comment: @bobajob i am familair with `NOW()` , the answer and code in it was to address the question raised by Ciara. But thanks anyhow

Comment: I'm quite sure you are, I was merely referring to the paragraph `I can'f figure out how to get it to pull the info from the current year while using this module. I tried using but I have to manually change it every year and I want it to autochange`, which suggested that this may be a helpful addition (though that may just be my misreading of it).

Comment: @bobajob thanks for the reference , now i understand your comment better

Comment: @bobajob feel free to add a section `Edit` in my answer below with your Tip +1

Comment: @ShaiRado that works perfectly! Thank you so much! I've been trying to figure it out all week!

Comment: @bobajob thank you also - the ' YEAR(NOW())-1 ' works a treat!